# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - python

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to access a JSON api and print only the "genres" but i keep getting the following error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

My code:

```
import urllib
import json

u = urllib.urlopen('http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=the%20big%20bang%20theory')
data = json.load(u)   


print data['genres']
```

if I just try:

```
print data
```

I get all the information back.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: what does the data look like?

Comment: Try adding a `print data` to debug this.

Comment: The JSON returned has a list a outer container, you should loop over it or get one item first.

Comment: [{u'score': 2.4287872, u'show': {u'status': u'Running', u'rating': {u'average': 8.4}, u'genres': [u'Comedy'], u'weight': 15, u'updated': etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the return type of `json.load`. `print(type(data))` will show, it is actually a `list`. For your specific example

```
for entry in data:
    print(entry['show']['genres'])
```

will do the trick.